# Conflict with JQuery libs while using Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

So I have this guy JS called form renderer, I make an AJAX request to get it and it automatically applies some funtions and properties to jQuery in order to render a form the way I want. But because I'm using webpack with another framework, it has two jQuery contexts... so, it applies the functions and properties to the right jQuery and when it's supposed to call a function from jQuery inside webpack, it calls the wrong jQuery whenever $ is used. With console if do

```js
window.$.fn.metaform
```

It gets the right function but if use inside of webpack it doesn't work... It creates a webpack provided window and it doesn't work.

This is the error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: __webpack_provided_window_dot_$.fn is not a function TypeError: __webpack_provided_window_dot_$.fn is not a function

```js
 buildForm() {

    ajax.getFormRenderer().then(() => {
      this.renderForm();
    });
  }

  renderForm() {

    if(formJSON != undefined) {
      $('#form').metaform('render', { form: formJSON, strings: { DEFAULT_SELECT: "Select...", SCRIPT_ERROR: "Error" } });
    }
  }
```

What should I do? Is there a way to use the jQuery I want?

Here's my webpack config

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var isProductionEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
var ENV = isProductionEnv ? 'PRODUCTION' : 'DEVELOPMENT';

console.log(ENV + ' ENV');

function getPlugins() {
  var plugins = [];

  plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '$': 'jquery',
    'jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  }));

  if (isProductionEnv) {
    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
  }

  return plugins;
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/main.js'),
    indicators:  path.resolve(__dirname,'js/indicators/main.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    //root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    alias: {
      app:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
      views:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/views'),
      utils:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/utils'),
      libs:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'libs/js'),
      components:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/components')
    },
  },
  plugins: getPlugins(),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you get `$` in your buildForm?

Comment: I added the answer to your question in my question.

Answer (score -1):

I think this link can help you. [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Quote:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.

Comment: Just by trying to use the noConflict like

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

It gets the wrong jQuery. Not the one I want. Even where I was sure it would get the correct one. Whenever I call jQuery inside webpack it gets the correct one, but if I try to use it in any manner it gets the other one.

Comment: it's hard to tell you only by the code you're provided. But I think if you're using `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` then it should be `window.$j.fn.metaform` and this should be changed as well `plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({`